# new to bash scripting; trying to figure out why SOURCE command doesn't execute

Tags: bash

I have made a really sincere effort to figure this out, and I just can't.  This is my very simple bash script.  The lines that begin "export" and "echo" seem to work, so I know my script is executing.  If I enter the line that begins "source" at the prompt in the terminal I get a lot of printed output that indicates that the command is running, but if I execute my script, nothing happens (and in fact subsequent efforts to use Freesurfer indicate that it hasn't worked). I have a feeling there may be something very basic I don't get about bash scripting, but I can't figure out what that thing is from looking at tutorials.

```
#!/bin/bash

export FREESURFER_HOME=/foo/freesurfer
echo "starting freesurfer"
echo $FREESURFER_HOME
source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/bar/my_dir
```

Comment: How do you execute this script? You need to `source` it as well for changes it makes to the environment to take effect in your current shell.

Comment: That does seem to have been the problem! I didn't realize I needed to use the source command, even though my script contained the source command.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you run your script using `./scriptname.sh` it is exexuted in a subshell. Every variable that is set there etc cannot change the environment of the parent shell. In order to do so you need to `source` the script.

See eg. this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)

Comment: Thanks! That's very clarifying.